# Symbols to represent each distinct symmetry of polyhedra

Tags: group-theory, notation, polyhedra, symmetry

Is there a pictorial or symbolic way to represent each distinct symmetry of a polyhedron?

Comment: It is just a particular case of the answer you expect, but this is at least a start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group

Comment: Here are a few other pages worth a look: [Polyhedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_group), [List of spherical symmetry groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spherical_symmetry_groups), [Point groups in three dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_groups_in_three_dimensions) (and pages linked to them)

Comment: None of these seem to provide a unique way to list each distinct symmetry? The sphere-like thing seems to classify the entire group "in general" by a single diagram.

Comment: Well, sure: You name the generating symmetries $\rho_0, \rho_1, \rho_2$ and the various symmetries are $\rho_0 \rho_1 \rho_2$ or $\rho_2 \rho_0 \rho_1 \rho_0 \rho_2$ or whatever. Are you looking for something more?

Comment: Looking for a particular pictorial diagram (unique for each configuration), rather than operators

Comment: also, can you explain more about how to reduce to get a base set of generating symmetries?